# How do I override "Mage_Customer_AccountController" in Magento 1.4.1.1?

Tags: overrides, controllers

I've made a new module called "Lpf_ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin" especially to override a method from Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php, using following files .

I want my method "_loginPostRedirect" to be called, instead of the one from "Mage_Customer_AccountController".

When I run my website, the new module seems not to be called (the former "_loginPostRedirect" method is called). I wonder why..

etc/modules/Lpf_ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lpf_ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Lpf_ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin>
    </modules>
</config>
```

etc/modules/Lpf_All.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lpf_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Lpf_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

code/local/Lpf/ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lpf_ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Lpf_ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
       <routers>
            <checkout>
             <args>
                <modules>
                 <Lpf_ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin before="Mage_Customer">Lpf_ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin</Lpf_ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin>
                </modules>
             </args>
            </checkout>
       </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

code/local/Lpf/ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin/controllers/AccountController.phtml

```
<?php

require_once "Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php";
class Lpf_ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
    # surcharge de _loginPostRedirect
    /**
     * Define target URL and redirect customer after logging in
     */
    protected function _loginPostRedirect()
    {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session");
        $urlBeforeLoginSuccess = $session->getData("urlBeforeLoginSuccess");
        $session = $this->_getSession();

        if (!$session->getBeforeAuthUrl() || $session->getBeforeAuthUrl() == Mage::getBaseUrl() ) {

            // Set default URL to redirect customer to
            $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getAccountUrl());

            // Redirect customer to the last page visited after logging in
            if ($session->isLoggedIn())
            {
                if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard')) {
                    if ($referer = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME)) {
                        $referer = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($referer);
                        if ($this->_isUrlInternal($referer)) {
                            $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($referer);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if ($session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {
                    $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
                }
            } else {
                $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl());
            }
        } else if ($session->getBeforeAuthUrl() == Mage::helper('customer')->getLogoutUrl()) {
            $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getDashboardUrl());
        }
        else {
            if (!$session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {
                //Removed $session->setAfterAuthUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl());
                $session->setAfterAuthUrl($urlBeforeLoginSuccess);
                Mage::log(__METHOD__ . 'surcharge urlBeforeLoginSuccess '.$urlBeforeLoginSuccess);
            }
            if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
                $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
                //Mage::log(__METHOD__ . ' 6 '.$urlBeforeLoginSuccess);
            }
        }
        $this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In config.xml of your module replace the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <frontend>
       <routers>
            <customer>
             <args>
                <modules>
                 <Lpf_ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin before="Mage_Customer">Lpf_ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin</Lpf_ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin>
                </modules>
             </args>
            </customer>
       </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountController.php');

Above code for include the AccountController in your controller

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I don't understand with what content I should replace config.xml. As the one you provided is similar to mine...

Comment: hello jolyqr just replace code from <frontend> tag to </frontend> .can you join me at skype:kinex.sourav

Answer (score 3):

First, `code/local/Lpf/ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin/controllers/AccountController.phtml` has the wrong file extension.  You want `php`, not `phtml`.

Second, since this is an older version of Magento, you might want to try the config-based rewrites like such:

```
<global>
  <routers>
    <cms><!-- route name --> 
      <rewrite> 
        <page><!-- controller name -->
          <actions>
            <!-- rewrite only the view action -->
            <view><!-- action name -->
              <to>target_route/target_controller/target_action</to>
            </view> 
          </actions> 
        </page> 
      </rewrite>
    </cms> 
  </routers> 
</global>
```

This was the way to do rewrites in legacy magento (pre 1.5.x).

This may or may not get you where you want to go, but it can be a starting point.

Comment: Thank you Ryan Street ! I've modified my file extension. But I'm pretty knew in magento, so I don't really know how to adapt my old "config.xml" with yours. Could you please provide the new "config.xml" ?

Answer (score 2):

The `<frontend><router>` handle in `code/local/Lpf/ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin/etc/config.xml` is wrong. It should be `<customer>` instead of `<checkout>`:

```
<frontend>
       <routers>
            <customer>
               ...
            </customer>
       </routers>
</frontend>
```

Comment: Thanks ! I made the changes, but still not working...

Answer (score 1):

When overrinding any function from code/local/Lpf/ModuleUrlBackAfterLogin/controllers/AccountController.phtml. The method "indexAction" should always be overriden (otherwise it won't work)  as follows if no custom codes need to be run,

```
public function indexAction()
{
    //no custom codes. 
    parent::indexAction();
}
```

or as follows whether custom codes need to be run

```
public function indexAction()
{
 // insert your custom code here...
}
```